# Is Framework7 only ui framework or it's like ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, html-framework-7

I have build app with Ionic framework. But when i looked in Framework7 i found it's UI (specially material design) is outstanding. Now as i didn't use Framework7 before and also i became confuse about several things. Could you please help me to answer some questions?

1. Can i build iOS and Android app with Framework7? (Like ionic)
2. Is Framework7 is only UI/ CSS framework for mobile app? (so that it can be use with other)
3. Is there any other like Phonegap can be use with framework7? (i saw some article that it can be integrated)

Reason why i am asking is, ionic framework beats every other hybrid framework in market. But i like Framework7 UI than ionic's default UI. In framework7 their native iOS app and Google material design is so perfect when i see their demo. So please share your experience or thoughts or any other tips.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you that the Framework7 UI is very nice. And you can use Phonegap and Framework 7 to create apps.

However, unlike ionic, Framework7 provides only UI/CSS functionality. So you will see that a lot of functionality that ionic provides is not available in Framework7. Ionic is builld on top of AngularJS, Framework7 is not, so most of the functionality that Angular provides is not available in Framework7.

Comment: Can't we use ionic and Framework7 together ?

Comment: can we use ionic with framework7 together?

Comment: Why would you want that? Use either Ionic with its own UI or use Framework7 together with for example Angular/React/Vue.